# Destructuring an object to match a functions expected argument interface

Tags: typescript

I have the following interfaces, function and object:

```
export interface GetCountyArgs {
  id?: number;
  title?: string;
}

export interface County {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  locationSet: [];
}

function myFunc(a:GetCountyArgs){
    console.log(a.id, a.title)
}

let county: County = {id:1, title:"Galway", locationSet:null};
```

I'm looking for a shorthand, if it exists, to destructure the 'County' object to match 'GetCountyArgs' interface as I pass it to 'myFunc'.

This is possible in multiple lines using the following destructuring syntax:

```
let x: GetCountyArgs;
({...county} = x);

myFunc(x)
```

However, I will be using interfaces in this manner a lot, and would like to know if there's a way to do this inline when invoking the method. I feel like there should be, but can't find any examples...

Cheers!

Comment: not getting you ....what do you mean by destrucutre

Comment: To break an object down to its component parts. The spread operator 'destructures' and object, for example. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: In my example `({...county} = x)` destructures the county objects fields, and assigns only the valid fields (id and title) to `x` which is only accepts those fields, but not the field locationSet.

Comment: so bascially you want to map property of one object to same property of another object ....right ?

Comment: Exactly, but some of these interfaces are quite large...

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, in this case `coutry` is the target and x the source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object that has at least a property id of number or title of string is compatible with *myFunc*:

```
myFunc({});
myFunc({ id: 2 });
myFunc({ title: "2" });
myFunc({ title: "2", id: 3 });
```

Depending on the type check flags defined in your tsconfig, myFunc will only refuse **literal** objects that have properties not defined in *GetCountyArgs*:

```
//does not type check
myFunc({ title: "2", id: 3, "stillWorks?": "no"}); // "stillWorks?" is not defined in the interface but...
//this way does.
var butThisWayDoes =  { title: "2", id: 3, "stillWorks?": "no" };
myFunc(butThisWayDoes);// it will not complain when passing a variable
```

So destructuring is not needed in this case and you don't need to declare a variable of type GetCountyArgs, it is not the name that matters only the structure. If the object is in a variable *just pass the variable*, if the function is invoked with a literal don't put in the literal any property that was not defined in the interface

Comment: Thanks, I read your answer yesterday but was too busy to reply. Although it's not a solution, it helped me get a better understanding of the issue, for which there is no solution. What I was hoping for was something along the lines of object 'reflection', but of course this isn't possible as JavaScript has no concept of interfaces, something I keep forgetting as I learn TS. Cheers for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.assign` to copy from x to country :

```
Object.assign(county, x);
```

Or if you don't mind creating a new object:

```
county = {
    ...county,
    ...x
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not really what I was asking, but creating a new object does indeed seem to be necessary.